# How to catch the lookup of non-existent nested variables on a Python class?

Tags: python

I'm trying to hijack any calls made to my class and pass them to a method of my choice on the class.

My class so far:

```
class Klass(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == '_dummy_func':
            return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        return object.__getattribute__(self, 'dummy_func')

    def _dummy_func(self):
        print 'dummy func called!'
```

which works when I do this:

```
cls = Klass()
cls.foo()
```

but falls over when trying to do this:

```
cls = Klass()
cls.foo.bar()
```

as `dummy_func` has no attribute `bar`.

I looked at trying to catch this nested behaviour in the `__getattribute__()` by checking to see if `name` is a function as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/624939/158304), however it's a string not the actual variable.

Is there a way to catch this from inside `Klass`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of returning a dummy *function*, just return a dummy *object* which is callable through the `__call__` method and in turn defines `__getattr__` to return *another* dummy object if an attribute is requested:

```
class Dummy(object):
  def __init__(self, klass, path):
    self.klass = klass
    self.path = path

  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    return Dummy(self.klass, self.path + [attr])

  def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
    self.klass._dummy_func(self.path, *args, **kw)

class Klass(object):
  def __getattr__(self, attr):
    return Dummy(self, [attr])

  def _dummy_func(self, path, *args, **kw):
    print "Dummy function %s called with %d arguments!" \
                      % ('.'.join(path), len(args))

Klass().foo.bar.func(1, 2)  
# => "Dummy function foo.bar.func called with 2 arguments!"
```

You can now apply your logic depending on the full path given to `_dummy_func`. You even get the supplied arguments and keywords to work with.

Comment: That is brilliant, thanks. It also covers further nesting of variables, which is perfect.

Comment: Nice use of `path` to remember the attribute lookup chain;  however, `Dummy.klass` is not actually a class, but an instance (it also is unused).

Comment: @Ethan: Look again. It's not named `klass` because it's a class, but because it's an instance of type `Klass`. It's also not unused (hint: line 10).

Comment: I am amazed.  When I first saw your code I thought it was convoluted and unnecessary, with mine being much simpler; now I see that you are using `Dummy` as a memory for the lookup chain, and when Python finally decides to call it simply passing that memory back to the original `Klass` object. Beautiful.  I take my hat off to you.

Comment: @Ethan Furman: I've rarely seen a comment like this on this site. I have to take *my* hat off to you for your fairness :)