# making a class callable in same instance

Tags: python, class, callable

```
class Foo(object):
    def tick(self):
        print("something")

class Bar(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo()

    def tick(self):
        #Here's what I do....
        self.foo.tick()

        #here's what my goal would be
        self.foo()

b = Bar()
b.tick()
```

That's essentially my goal. From what I've gathered I could change the tick function to `__call__` and that would allow me to do what I wanted. A couple of the other answers said that this would make a new instance of the object, does that mean that it would use self.foo's memory? or would it make a whole new object, newly instanced? or make a copy of self.foo?

Also a couple of drawbacks to this which may or may not manifest themselves come to mind. For a particular part of my program, I check to see if the object has a `__call__` to determine if the argument I'm passing is a function or a variable, and I don't really think I would want to allow that to be called (even though, I suppose the class technically would be a function at that point.) Is there any way to distinguish between a function and a callable class?

Is there anything else that would make doing this undesirable (and is it a pythonic way to work?)? My next thought had been that given that other variable prefixed with `__` cant be used outside their class, but that doesnt seem to be the case here.

Comment: Implementing `__call__` would *not* create new instances of the object. Doing `TheClass()` creates a new instance but `some_instance()` simply calls `__call__`.

Comment: I'm only mentioning this in case you haven't thought of it -- But, with the extremely simple code you have above, making `Bar` inherit from `Foo` seems like a good bet -- Of course your use-case might make it not a good bet ...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Changing `tick(self)` to `__call__(self)` is the correct solution.

This has nothing to do with memory allocation. All `__call__` signifies is the function which Python calls when you use (for an object `foo`) the syntax `foo()`.

For your later question: to check whether something is an object, use `isinstance` or `issubclass` (possibly with the `object` class). And in my mind [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/624948/383402) is better than the accepted one for the "How do I determine if something is a function?" question you've probably seen.

Answer (score 22):

To make a class instance callable, all you need to do is implement a `__call__` method.  Then, to call the `__call__` method, you just do:  `instance(arg1,arg2,...)` -- in other words, you call the instance the same way you would call a function.

Note that you can alias `__call__` with some other method defined on the class if you want:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def tick(self):
...         print ("something")
...     __call__ = tick
... 
>>> a = Foo()
>>> a()
something
>>> a.tick()
something
```

Comment: if you were to implement a function that takes arguments, can you still use this aliasing method? or does it only work when the function has only one argument `self`

Comment: I'm trying to make it so that different instances have different __call__ methods. However, if I set self.__call__ within __init__(), when I actually call instance(), I get TypeError: 'CallableClass' object is not callable. Is there a way to set __call__ differently instance-to-instance?

Comment: You can have a `_delegate` property which `__call__` will delegate to:  `def __call__(self): self._delegate()`