# Is there a way in Python to check whether an entry to os.environ is a variable or a shell function?

Tags: python, bash, shell, environment-variables

With the `os` module in Python we can easily access environment variables through the dict `os.environ`. However, I found out that `os.environ` does not just hold variables, but also globally defined shell functions (e.g. from the `module` software package).

Is it possible from within Python to find out whether a given entry in `os.environ` actually is a function and not a variable? Please note that a **shell-agnostic solution is preferred**, but I could settle for a Bash-specific solution as well.

Comment: Is a python function, or a bash shell function?

Comment: You can check a Python variable to see if it's callable as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624926/how-to-detect-whether-a-python-variable-is-a-function- but I'm interested in what you're doing to add shell functions to `os.environ`. That seems odd to me.

Comment: As posted below, if you export shell functions with `export -f fn` or `declare -fx fn` then function `fn` will end up in `os.environ`.

Comment: @VooDooNOFX: A bash shell function is what I try to figure out.

Comment: @Thrustmaster: `export tt='() aw, dayum!; echo $tt` leaves me with `() aw, dayum!`, so in this case we would get a false positive. Since this is a script that will be deployed on very heterogenous systems I cannot rely on not having any variable content start with `()`.

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke But that's the only way to do. If I do `export tt=$'() { echo 1\n}'; bash -c tt`, I get a 1. SO that's the only one you can rely on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This feature is bash-specific, so a test for an exported shell function needs to do what Bash does. Experimentation and [source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c#n341) show that Bash recognizes an environment variable as a shell function at startup by the presence of a `() {` prefix in its value — if the prefix is missing, or even slightly altered, the variable is treated as an ordinary data variable.

Therefore, the equivalent Python check would look like this:

```
def is_env_shell_func(name):
    return os.environ[name].startswith('() {')
```

Comment: Again, I think this will return `True` for any variable that starts with `() {`, not just functions.

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke That's a feature, because this is exactly what [the shell does](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/variables.c#n341) to recognize such variables. I've now amended the answer to mention this.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow... if I create a variable as `export not_a_function='() { wololo }' and run `declare -f not_a_function`, it tells by way of return code `1` that `not_a_function` is, in fact, not a function. But maybe I misunderstand you.

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke What I get in Bash 4.2.45 is `error importing function definition for `not_a_function'` when starting a subshell, so Bash obviously **tries** to define the function. And if you fix the definition so it works, by including a newline before the closing brace, then the definition tests and works just fine.

Comment: Would you be so kind to post the lines of code you used to trigger the described behavior? I am not able to reproduce it with Bash 3.2 or 4.1.

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke I've added them to the answer.

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke Also, judging by the source of `initialize_shell_variables` in Bash 4.1.1, it does the exact same thing.

Comment: Aha! Now I finally get it :) It seems that you have to invoke `bash` again to make it work as a function, i.e. if you just export it, the current shell does not yet recognize it as a function.

Comment: @MichaelSchlottke Yes; I've now added "at startup" to the relevant sentence of the answer.

Answer (score 3):

One solution that I find to work (but that is ridiculously clumsy) is the following:

```
import subprocess

var = 'my_variable_name_i_want_to_check'
p = subprocess.Popen('declare -f ' + var, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate()

if p.returncode == 0:
    print('function')
else:
    print('variable')
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure shell functions are there in os.environ?

```
{master>}% function test_fn() {
function> echo "Hello";
function> }
{master>}% test_fn
Hello
{master>}% python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 13:56:14) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['test_fn']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'test_fn'
>>> os.environ.keys()
['SSH_ASKPASS', 'PS_FORMAT', 'GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE', 'GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID', 'WINDOWPATH', 'LOGNAME', 'USER', 'GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL', 'HOME', 'PS1', 'DISPLAY', 'PATH', 'LANG', 'TERM', 'SHELL', 'SSH_AGENT_PID', 'XAUTHORITY', 'LANGUAGE', 'GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE', 'SHLVL', 'GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM', 'WINDOWID', 'EDITOR', 'MANPATH', 'GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS', 'GPG_AGENT_INFO', 'USERNAME', 'WORKON_HOME', 'COLORTERM', 'WORDCHARS', 'SSH_AUTH_SOCK', 'TMUX', 'GDMSESSION', 'XDG_SESSION_COOKIE', 'LS_OPTIONS', 'DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS', '_', 'VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR', 'VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME', 'DESKTOP_SESSION', 'GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES', 'GNOME_KEYRING_PID', 'WINDOW_MANAGER', 'ZBEEP', 'PYTHONSTARTUP', 'OLDPWD', 'SESSION_MANAGER', 'XDG_DATA_DIRS', 'PWD', 'CFLAGS', 'VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_LOG_DIR', 'LS_COLORS', 'TMUX_PANE']
>>>
```

Comment: Yes, you need to do: `export -f test_fn`, before invoking a child process.

Comment: Yes, alternatively you can use `declare -fx test_fn`.