# How to check the type of an object against the type "function"

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

I am wiriting a script in which I would like to verify if a given argumente to a function is itself a function. I have checked in the IDLE the `type()` of that argument.
Let us assume that the argumente is called `a` and that I **know** that `a` is a function.

When I type `type(a)` in the Shell, this gets printed:
`<class 'function'>`

But if I try to type this:
`type(add) == function`
It gives me a NameError: name 'function' is not defined
(That was not my only attempt, but if I put them all here this will get too long)

I think I understand that part, because I think `function` is not a keyword like `int` or `float`, which lets me do conditionals like `type(3) == int`

But, knowing this, how can I check if something is from a given built-in type, if that type does not have a specific keyword (or maybe, those keywords are not that well-known)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This will probably help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624926/how-to-detect-whether-a-python-variable-is-a-function

Comment: Thank you man. Great answers on that link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [isinstance](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) built-in to check if the type of a variable conforms to a type of a function. Unfortunately, as there is no short hand to create a function type just like `int` you can import [types](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html) and check with [types.FunctionType](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.FunctionType)

```
>>> import types
>>> isinstance(add, types.FunctionType)
True
```

you can also import [isfunction](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.isfunction) from [inspect](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) to perform the same check

```
import inspect
inspect.isfunction(add)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from inspect import isfunction

isfunction(a)
```