# How to check that variable is a lambda function

Tags: python, types, lambda

I'm working on a project, which contains several modules. Simplifying the problem, there is some variable x. Sometimes it may be int or float or list. But it may be a lambda function, and should be treated in different way. How to check that variable x is a lambda?

For example

```
>>> x = 3
>>> type(x)
<type 'int'>
>>> type(x) is int
True
>>> x = 3.4
>>> type(x)
<type 'float'>
>>> type(x) is float
True
>>> x = lambda d:d*d
>>> type(x)
<type 'function'>
>>> type(x) is lambda
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    type(x) is lambda
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> type(x) is function
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
>>>
```

Comment: Closely related: [How do I detect whether a Python variable is a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624926/how-do-i-detect-whether-a-python-variable-is-a-function)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use [`types.LambdaType`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/types.html#types.LambdaType) or `types.FunctionType` to make sure that the object is a function object like this

```
x = lambda d:d*d
import types
print type(x) is types.LambdaType
# True
print isinstance(x, types.LambdaType)
# True
```

and then you need to check the name as well to make sure that we are dealing with a lambda function, like this

```
x = lambda x: None
def y(): pass
print y.__name__
# y
print x.__name__
# <lambda>
```

So, we put together both these checks like this

```
def is_lambda_function(obj):
    return isinstance(obj, types.LambdaType) and obj.__name__ == "<lambda>"
```

As @Blckknght suggests, if you want to check if the object is just a callable object, then you can use the builtin [`callable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#callable) function.

Comment: `isinstance(x, types.LambdaType)` looks more idiomatic.

Comment: It's worth noting that `types.LambdaType` is an alias for `types.FunctionType`. There's no (easy or reliable) way to tell the difference between a lambda function and one created with `def`.

Comment: @Blckknght That is why we need to check the `__name__` as well :-)

Comment: so it should be to step procedure type(x) is types.LambdaType and x.__name__ == '<lambda>'. Right?

Comment: @rth You are correct. I included a `is_lambda_function` as well, please check.

Comment: Ah, I see I hadn't payed enough attention to the end of the answer, and you've already addressed the issue of lambdas versus regular functions. I'd suggest though that there probably isn't much need to tell the difference. If your code really cares how a given function was defined, you're probably doing it wrong. Most of the time you should use "duck typing" rather than strict type checks. If you expect a function, accept anything that is callable (such as a class, or an instance of a class with a `__call__` method). If you do need to check up front, use the builtin `callable` function.

Comment: @Blckknght Thanks :-) I included that as well in the answer.

Comment: `__name__` can be changed. Alternatively, use `__code__.co_name`, which contains the name of the function/lambda at the time it was compiled and is read-only. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54094263/how-to-find-out-if-a-function-has-been-declared-by-lambda-or-def/64301482#64301482

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer the `typing` module, use `Callable`:

```py
In [1]: from typing import Callable
In [2]: isinstance(lambda: None, Callable)
Out[2]: True
```

Comment: what is the difference between your solution and  @Blckknght  suggestion to use `callable` built-in function?

Comment: @rth you can't use `callable()` for typing hinting your signatures

Comment: A regular function (not lambda) also returns True: `def x(): pass`, `isinstance(x, Callable)` ->`True`. So I don't see any advantage of your answer vs @thefourtheye one.

Comment: 1) your question should specify that you want to discriminate between lambda functions and ordinary functions if that is a requirement. 2) `callable(lambda: None) == True`

Comment: I don't know how to make more specific, it is in the title **How to check that variable is a lambda function** :) Thank you for additional answer!

Comment: This isn't exactly correct. This gets you any *callable*, not function objects specifically. And generally, if you want to check if something is callable, you should just use the builtin `callable`, e.g. `callable(lambda: None)`. Indeed, I am surprised this even worked, and it only works because this inherits from `collections.abc.Callable` which would probably be what you want to use for runtime checks anyway...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I testing using the built-in `callable` in place of `typing.Callable` to type hint in a function signature. That did not work with the runtime type validator we use (`typeguard`).

Comment: @crypdick no, *it isn't a type* it's a function that checks if an object is callable, it's for *runtime type checking* not static analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Can consider the following:

```
type(x) == type(lambda x:x)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.