# How to find out if a function has been declared by `lambda` or `def`?

Tags: python, function, lambda, types, function-declaration

If I declare two functions `a` and `b`:

```
def a(x):
    return x**2

b = lambda x: x**2
```

I can not use `type` to differentiate them, since they're both of the same type.

```
assert type(a) == type(b)
```

Also, `types.LambdaType` doesn't help:

```
>>> import types
>>> isinstance(a, types.LambdaType)
True
>>> isinstance(b, types.LambdaType)
True
```

One could use `__name__` like:

```
def is_lambda_function(function):
    return function.__name__ == "<lambda>"

>>> is_lambda_function(a)
False
>>> is_lambda_function(b)
True
```

However, since `__name__` could have been modified, `is_lambda_function` is not guaranteed to return the correct result:

```
>>> a.__name__ = '<lambda>'
>>> is_lambda_function(a)
True
```

Is there a way which produces a more reliable result than the `__name__` attribute?

Comment: Is there any practical use case where you would actually need this?

Comment: Also there may be some objects that are neither but callable, and Python builtin functions.

Comment: Along with the other comment above, what difference does it make whether it's a def or a lambda?

Comment: @JaredSmith, e.g. Django cannot serialize Lambdas.

Comment: @jpp: IMHO it is not a duplicate! The accepted answer for the other question clearly refers Python2 while Python3 is more currently used nowadays. And it cannot be applied in Python3...

Comment: @jpp https://stackoverflow.com/a/23852434/521776 this answer is applicable to py3 as well

Comment: What is your use case?

Comment: It's hard to know without your use case, but likely you can duck tape this, i.e. `try` something that only works with def functions, `except` the specific raised exception and proceed as you want

Comment: @Kanak In this case: Try to serialize it with Django?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12264834/what-is-the-difference-for-python-between-lambda-and-regular-function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot reliably in Python 3.

Python 2 used to define a bunch of function types. For that reason, methods, lambdas and plain functions have each their own type.

Python 3 has only one type which is `function`. There are indeed different side effects where declaring a regular function with `def` and a `lambda`: `def` sets the name to the name (and qualified name) of the function and can set a docstring, while `lambda` sets the name (and qualified name) to be `<lambda>`, and sets the docstring to None. But as this can be changed...

If the functions are loaded from a regular Python source (and not typed in an interactive environment), the `inspect` module allows to access the original Python code:

```
import inspect

def f(x):
    return x**2

g = lambda x: x**2

def is_lambda_func(f):
    """Tests whether f was declared as a lambda.

Returns: True for a lambda, False for a function or method declared with def
Raises:
    TypeError if f in not a function
    OSError('could not get source code') if f was not declared in a Python module
                                         but (for example) in an interactive session
"""
    if not inspect.isfunction(f):
        raise TypeError('not a function')
    src = inspect.getsource(f)
    return not src.startswith('def') and not src.startswith('@') # provision for decorated funcs

g.__name__ = 'g'
g.__qualname__ = 'g'

print(f, is_lambda_func(f))
print(g, is_lambda_func(g))
```

This will print:

```
<function f at 0x00000253957B7840> False
<function g at 0x00000253957B78C8> True
```

By the way, if the problem was serialization of function, a function declared as a lambda can successfully be pickled, provided you give it a unique qualified name:

```
>>> g = lambda x: 3*x
>>> g.__qualname__ = "g"
>>> pickle.dumps(g)
b'\x80\x03c__main__\ng\nq\x00.'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check `__code__.co_name`. It contains what the name was at the time the function/lambda was compiled:

```py
def a(x):
    return x**2

b = lambda x: x**2

def is_lambda_function(f):
    return f.__code__.co_name == "<lambda>"

>>> is_lambda_function(a)
False
>>> is_lambda_function(b)
True
```

And, contrary to `__name__`, `__code__.co_name` is [read-only](https://medium.com/@vadimpushtaev/name-of-python-function-e6d650806c4)...

```py
>>> a.__name__ = "<lambda>"
>>> b.__name__ = "b"

>>> a.__code__.co_name = "<lambda>"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: readonly attribute

>>> b.__code__.co_name = "b"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: readonly attribute
```

... so the results will stay the same:

```py
>>> is_lambda_function(a)
False
>>> is_lambda_function(b)
True
```

Answer (score 1):

I took the chance to dive in [cpython's source](https://github.com/python/cpython) to see if I could find anything, and I am afraid I have to second [Serge's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54095234/521776): you cannot.

Briefly, this is a lambda's journey in the interpreter:

1. During parsing, lambdas, just like every other expression, [are read into](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3bb183d7fb83ad6a84ec13dea90f95d67be35c69/Python/symtable.c#L1389)  an [expr_ty](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3bb183d7fb83ad6a84ec13dea90f95d67be35c69/Include/Python-ast.h#L215), which is a huge union containing data of every expression.
2. This `expr_ty` is then converted to the appropriate type ([Lambda](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3f22811fef73aec848d961593d95fa877f77ecbf/Python/Python-ast.c#L5738), in our case)
3. After some time we land into [the function that compiles lambdas](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f7e4d3642fbb88f4e6243c952a0e223fb5df1c65/Python/compile.c#L2435)
4. This function calls [assemble](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f7e4d3642fbb88f4e6243c952a0e223fb5df1c65/Python/compile.c#L5648), which calls [makecode](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f7e4d3642fbb88f4e6243c952a0e223fb5df1c65/Python/compile.c#L5530), which initializes a [PyCodeObject](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ec13b9322d95a651606219469fc7b7e9c977f248/Objects/codeobject.c#L98) (functions, methods, as well as lambdas, all end up here).

From this, I don't see anything particular that is specific to lambdas. This, combined with the fact that Python lets you modify pretty much every attribute of objects makes me/us believe what you want to do is not possible.

Comment: To amplify your answer: Since `def` and `lambda` produce indistinguishable objects (particularly since you can freely edit `__name__` and `__qualname__`), then not only is it "not possible" to do what OP asks, it's *not meaningful*. How do you tell the difference between a list produced by a list comprehension versus a list created by the `list` function and populated by a `for` loop? How do you tell the difference between a string produced by single-quotes versus a string produced by double-quotes? You can't, because there *is no difference*, except at the source code level.