# Is isinstance(lambda, type(lambda)) correct?

Tags: python

Are there any caveats to `isinstance(fn, type(lambda: 1))`? I'm aware of [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852423/how-to-check-that-variable-is-a-lambda-function#answer-23852434), but mine spares an import.

**Clarification**:

- `callable` doesn't cut it - `class` false positive
- *Context*: `pickle` can't pickle lambdas, must filter out of objects before pickling them. This includes local function definitions via `def`, but my method above covers it.
- *Question purpose*: to know of possible (1) memory, (2) correctness implications. (1): is `lambda: 1` garbage-collected? (2): will my approach detect any objects *other than* lambdas, functions, and local functions?

---

**Minimal code**: (I know there's a shorter way here, but not in the full context)

```py
for key, val in obj.items():
    if isinstance(val, type(lambda: 1)):  # can't pickle lambdas
        to_exclude.append(key)

to_save = {k:v for k,v in obj.items() if k not in to_exclude}
pickle.dump(to_save, file)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "caveats" and "spare an import"? ``types`` is often already imported, because many modules use it. Also note that ``type(lambda: 1)``  will create a function, lookup ``type``, and throw away the function *every time* the statement is run.

Comment: There is a caveat. It's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve with `type(lambda: 1)`. As per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23852423/how-to-check-that-variable-is-a-lambda-function#comment36708607_23852434) duck typing is recommended.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want to test? Whether it is a `lambda`, as opposed to a `def` function? Whether it's any callable function, but not e.g. a class? Including or excluding builtin functions? Would `callable` work or you?

Comment: `isinstance(fn, type(lambda: 1))` detects a regular python function as lambda as well.

Comment: "Purpose: ``pickle`` can't pickle lambdas" This is totally unrelated to lambda functions being lambda functions. It is related to lambda functions not have a registered name, which also affects many other objects. Do you *really* just want to filter out functions (``def`` and ``lambda``) or actually unpickle'able objects?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I did figure "created & destroyed" as a caveat, but I suspect Python's garbage collector takes care of it memory-wise, and performance-wise it isn't a concern. As for the purpose, the question isn't asking "how to filter all un-pickle-able objects" - my current problem is only with local functions.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Note that if you are using ``pickle``, that also imports ``types`` into the interpreter – so "importing" it yourself for your own use is only a name-binding. If your goals is finding *local* or *any* functions, please edit your question to clearly say so.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi The goal is to find lambdas / local functions that are _attributes of objects_, which should be conveyed by the second bullet. My beef with `import types` is that this is the one and only use case I'll have for it in my entire package, and can actually be _less understandable_ to broader audiences (one doesn't typically use `types`).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon It seems like the correct thing *to satisfy your actual goal* is to check whether `fn.__qualname__` points to `fn` (this is basically how ``pickle`` works). But so far your question still doesn't clearly say what your actual goal is – so far you have given the criteria "is a lambda", "is a function", "is a local function", and "is an attribute", which are likely Ys in an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Not really, my 'actual goal' is as-stated; the problem I'm trying to solve is already solved - I just seek to know whether there are caveats worth nothing with my approach, which in itself is a legitimate inquiry. Earlier you noted "which also affects many other objects" - is this to imply it'd detect anything other than lambdas, functions, or local functions? _That_ I'm interested to know.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon "which also affects many other objects" was in relation to ``lambda`` functions being unpickle'able not because they are ``lambda``s but because they *usually* don't have a registered name (their ``__module__`` and ``__qualname__`` does not point to them). Not having a registered name is not exclusive to ``lambda``s, but can also affect other objects. In fact, a ``lambda`` *can* be registered properly if needed. So if your purpose is to find unpickle'able functions, *both* ``type(lambda:1)`` and ``types.FunctionType`` are wrong.

Comment: Can you please clarify your *Question purpose*? What makes you think ``lambda:1`` isn't garbage collected? All Python implementations are garbage collected, ``lambda`` is not a special type, and calling ``type`` does not change that. What makes you think that this has correctness implications? ``type(lambda: 1)`` is the same object as ``types.FunctionType``.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Think you pretty much answered my question - what remains is: I get that other objects can be unnamed also, but my approach in particular will not detect them, correct? I'm not checking their module & qualname attributes, only type. And thanks for explaining some pickling ideas, am not too familiar.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from creating an instance of a lambda just to get a type, there should be no problem with it.   It will match `def function` as well as lambdas which makes the condition somewhat misleading relative to your intent.

If you merely need to know if fn is a callable object (function or lambda) you should express this as `callable(fn)` which better conveys your intention.

Comment: Note that classes are also `callable` (the constructor...)

Comment: That's usually a good thing. In most cases, classes which take a single parameter are just converters from the parameter type to class instances. Very convenient. IME that's a common use case for things like `int` or `str`.

Comment: Agreed on readability, but even doing it "Pythonically" doesn't clarify everything - so I just comment `# can't pickle lambdas`. As far as my approach goes, does Python's garbage collector handle the discarded lambda?

Comment: I all comes down to the intended purpose.  The expression `isinstance(fn, type(lambda: 1))` suggests that the intent is to not accept class constructors nor functions.  We would have to parse the rest of the code to determine if the condition is appropriate.  More likely than not, it is a condition to obtain a value using fn() which would work for any callable and may not need to exclude constructors (or Class.__call__ methods of instances)

Comment: @AlainT. `isinstance(fn, type(lambda: 1))` does not detect class constructors.

Comment: That's what I meant: "the intent is not to accept class constructor".  The question is: was that really the intent ?

Comment: Ah, alright - not the intent, but that shouldn't be conveyed in the full context, and it isn't what's actually checked anyway.