# Python: Substitute variable values before passing to another function

Tags: python, string, variable-substitution

I want to determine whether the input string is a valid function name or not.
Is there any way to substitute the value of the variable before being passed to isfunction call ?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def testFunc():
    print "Hello world!";
    return;

myString = "testFunc";
isfunction(testFunc); // This returns **True**
isfunction(myString); // This returns **False**
```

Comment: Do you mean that the _string_ is a valid function name, or the _variable_ is a function?

Comment: @khelwood: I want to know the value present inside myString is valid or not

Comment: Possible duplicate:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624926/how-to-detect-whether-a-python-variable-is-a-function

Comment: @Ashwin Then why should `isfunction(myString)` return false when `myString` is `"testFunc"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing that is using `eval`, which interprets string as code:

```
try:
    eval(myString)
except NameError:
    # not a function
```

Comment: This would execute any code that the string contains, and could cause far more errors than NameError can capture.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to check to see if there exists a loaded function with You could try this:

```
try:
    if hasattr(myString, '__call__'):
        func = myString
    elif myString in dir(__builtins__):
        func = eval(myString)
    else:
        func = globals()[myString]

except KeyError:
    #this is the fail condition

# you can use func()
```

The first `if` is actually unnecessary if you will always guarantee that myString is actually a string and not a function object, I just added it to be safe.

In any case, if you actually plan on executing these functions, I'd tread carefully. Executing arbitrary functions can be risky business.

EDIT:

I added another line to be a bit more sure we don't actually execute code unless we want to. Also changed it so that it is a bit neater

Comment: hasattr returns False because it considers myString as String variable

Comment: You are correct. Which is why the other conditions exist.