# programatically find all functions that are in use, recursively

Tags: python, disassembly

Starting from a script foo.py find all functions that are in use in local source code (i.e not built-in or third party packages), recursively.

**EDIT: I do not want to find recursive functions. I want to find all functions that are in use!**

e.g. foo.py

```
import bar

def not_used():
    pass

bar.do_stuff(x,y)
```

bar.py

```
import math

def more_stuff(x,y):
    result = math.abs(-x+-y)
    return result

def do_stuff(x,y):
    more_stuff(x,y)
```

Should return do_stuff & more_stuff

Should ignore not_used & abs

Many thanks

**EDIT: Code so far**

```
import dis

py_file = 'foo.py'

with open(py_file) as file:
    source_code = file.read()

compiled = compile(source_code, py_file, "exec")

funcs = []
byte_code = dis.Bytecode(compiled)
instructions = list(reversed([x for x in byte_code]))

for (ix, instruction) in enumerate(instructions):
    if instruction.opname == "CALL_FUNCTION":
        load_func_instr = instructions[ix + instruction.arg + 1]
        funcs.append(load_func_instr.argval)

results = [f'{ix}: {funcname}'for (ix, funcname) in enumerate(reversed(funcs), 1)]
```

Comment: Please define "in use", because it seems to me that `math.abs` should be considered "in use" here.

Comment: @Leporello good point, updated. thanks.

Comment: @Anonymous this is quite old, but if you still got the code it would be cool, if you could share your solution to avoid "reinventing the wheel" as you fittingly pointed in a comment below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python's [ast (abstract syntax tree)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module

A short example:

```py
import ast

code = """
import math

def more_stuff(x,y):
    result = math.abs(-x+-y)
    return result

def do_stuff(x,y):
    more_stuff(x,y)
"""

tree = ast.parse(code)

funcs = [x for x in ast.walk(tree) if isinstance(x, ast.FunctionDef)]

print(', '.join(f.name for f in funcs))
```

prints:

```
more_stuff, do_stuff
```

now you can add the tests, you like. For example the SO question
[How to find/detect if a build-in function is used in Python AST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37217823/how-to-find-detect-if-a-build-in-function-is-used-in-python-ast)

discusses how to detect if a function is being used.

Comment: Thanks @snow-bunting not really what I'm after, as it would pick-up all the unused functions and it doesn't resolve files that are referenced in imports. But I think a combination of the two approaches could probably work. I was going to write something, but I thought that somebody must've done this before and I hate reinventing the wheel - hence asking on here.