# How capture all non-built-in functions' names from a module and put them into a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to capture the name of ALL non-built-in functions from a specific module and put them into a list.

Let's say I wrote `func_1()` and `func_2()` inside the module `test.py`. Then, from inside another module, I want to do something like:

```
import test
my_list_of_functions = all_funcs_from(test)
```

`Dir()` returns built-in functions together, and I wasn't able to do the tricky with `help()`

Comment: `dir` should not return built-in functions.

Comment: `dir` returns things like `__builtins__`, `__doc__`, `__file__`, `__name__`, `__package__`.

Comment: None of those are functions.

Comment: @user2357112 sorry then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the function names in your module with [`inspect.getmembers`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers)

> Return all the members of an object in a list of (name, value) pairs
>   sorted by name. If the optional predicate argument is supplied, only
>   members for which the predicate returns a true value are included.

```
import types, inspect

# my_module is your module
r = inspect.getmembers(my_module, lambda o: isinstance(o, types.FunctionType))
function_names = [i[0] for i in r] # list of only function names
```

You can simplify the predicate by using `inspect.isfunction`(credits to @user2357112):

```
r = inspect.getmembers(my_module, inspect.isfuction)
function_names = [i[0] for i in r]
```

Comment: You can supply `inspect.isfunction` for the predicate.

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks. Right away!

Comment: @moses-koledoye Almost that. But it is returning the name of only one of the functions from the module, and returns it several times like this: `[('description', <function description at 0x10788e9b0>), ('description', <function description at 0x10788e9b0>), ('description', <function description at 0x10788e9b0>), ('description', <function description at 0x10788e9b0>), ('description', <function description at 0x10788e9b0>)]`

Comment: @MosesKoledoye It worked with `inspect.isfunction`. Thank you very much, Moses!

Comment: @anquadros Please note that top-level functions returned by ``functools.partial`` are not functions in the sense of ``inspect.isfunction`` and ``isinstance(f, types.FunctionType)``.

Answer (score 2):

This should return all top-level functions from the imported module.

```
from types import FunctionType

def all_funcs_from(module):
    return filter(lambda f: isinstance(f, FunctionType), module.__dict__.values())
```

Builtin functions are of type `types.BuiltinFunctionType`.
But note that something like `f = functools.partial(g, 5)` would not be captured by this method.

You can also use `hasattr(f, '__call__')` to widen your search for callables in general.

All this depends on your actual requirements.

*The answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624926/how-to-detect-whether-a-python-variable-is-a-function) are very helpful in this regard.*