# Create series from python object, include its @property

Tags: python, pandas

To create a `pandas.Series` from a generic object, the following can be used:

```
import datetime

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.creation = datetime.datetime.now()

a = Test()
c = pandas.Series(a.__dict__)
```

This results in a Series that is described as

```
creation   2017-12-17 09:51:48.157503
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

This failed to work if the object contains "attributes" created using `@property`, like so

```
class Test(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.creation = datetime.datetime.now()

    @property
    def as_string(self):
        return 'Test at {}'.format(self.creation)

a = Test()
c = pandas.Series(a.__dict__) # same as above
```

How can the object's properties be included in the `Series`? Or is there an easier way to create a `Series` from a generic object, including its properties?

Comment: Think about this semantically... how useful would it be to put these disparate properties into a single series?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: this is supposed to be a MCVE. In reality, it's a bit more complicated: there is a list of data objects with properties. These should be included in a dataframe.

Comment: Oh... well, here's a filthy way of doing it: `pd.Series([getattr(a, x) for x in dir(a) if not x.startswith('__')])`. Can't think of a better way.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ:thank you. Now all that's missing is to get rid of those `<bound method...`s and `<function...`s that get added.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/624926/4909087 And modify your if statement a bit.

Comment: By the way, keep in mind that @property is actually an attribute of the class, not the instance, (for example, try `Test.__dict__` and see what comes out).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

```
def data_properties(obj):
    def _props(obj):
        for attr in dir(obj):
            if attr.startswith('__'):
                continue
            val = getattr(obj, attr)
            if not callable(val):
                yield (attr, val)
    return dict(_props(obj))
```

You can use it this way:

```
import datetime
import pandas


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = datetime.datetime.now()

    @property
    def y(self):
        return 5

    def method(self, x):
        return self.y * x


f = Foo()
pd.Series(data_properties(f))
# x    2017-12-17 07:09:20.694000
# y                             5
# dtype: object
```

The benefit of the approach is that the `_props` generator can be easily modified to fine-tune the results if you have other constraints on what you'd like to have in your resulting series.