# How to display and select function in Python 3?

Tags: python

I currently have two Python 3 scripts: **chooseFunc.py** and **testFuncs.py**.

My goal is to write a function `chooseFunction` in the former script, then import the function for usage within the latter script. Upon execution of `chooseFunction()` in **testFuncs.py**, it should display the functions present in   **testFuncs.py** and allow the user to choose which `func()` to run. The`func`s have no `args` for the purpose at hand.

I've created a function `chooseFunction` as such:

```
def chooseFunction(module):
    funcList = []

    for key, value in module.__dict__.items():
        if callable(value) and value.__name__ !='<lambda>' and  value.__name__ !='chooseFunction':
            funcList.append(value)

    for funcIdx, myFunc in enumerate(funcList):
        print(funcIdx, myFunc.__name__ )

    chosenIdx = int(input('Choose function... ·\n'))

    return funcList[chosenIdx]()
```

Currently, when executed in   **testFuncs.py** as follows:

```
from chooseFunc import chooseFunction
import sys

def func1():
    print('func1')

def func2():
    print('func2')

chooseFunction(module=sys.modules[__name__])
```

the argument `module=sys.modules[__name__]` on the last row  has to be provided.

How do I change this behavior such that `chooseFunction` retrieves the list of functions present in **testFuncs.py**, *without* having to provide the `module` argument above?

*Apologies in advance for any potential inconsistencies, this is my first entry on Stack Exchange... General feedback is appreciated!*

Answer (score 2):

Not quite to the specification you need (i.e. this is just a 1-file solution):

You can use [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) to get the [global symbol table](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/09/18/python-internals-symbol-tables-part-1/) and make an iterable that lists all the [`callable()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/624939/7455070) functions

As a dictionary:

```py
funcs = {k:v for k, v in list(globals().items()) if callable(v)}
```

Or as a list:

```py
funcs = [v for _,v in list(globals().items()) if callable(v)]
```

## Example Useage:

```py
# functions.py

def func1(msg):
    print("This is func 1: " + msg)

def func2(msg):
    print("This is func 2: " + msg)

def func3(msg):
    print("This is func 3: " + msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    funcs = [v for _,v in list(globals().items()) if callable(v)]

    # Prompt user for choice
    print("Choose function to run:")
    for i, f in enumerate(funcs):
        print('\t[{:d}] {:s}'.format(i+1, f.__name__))
    user_choice = int(input('\n>>> ')) - 1

    # Run the function
    funcs[user_choice]('hello there')
```

### Terminal output:

```
$ python functions.py
Choose function to run:
    [1] func1
    [2] func2
    [3] func3

>>> 2
This is func 2: hello there
```

Comment: Thank you Jamie. Although it doesn't fully answer my question (my code also successfully runs "chooseFunction" if called within same script, with dummy "testFuncs" present of course), your answer is still insightful to a Python newbie like me. This is much more readable :)