# Is there any way I can get all of the functions of a module so I can call them?

Tags: python

Is there any way I can get all of the functions of a module so I can call them?

If I say:

m.py:

```
__all__ = ['Bark']
def Bark():
    print('Bark')
```

main.py:

```
import m
for f in m.__all__:
   print(m.f)
```

I get an AttributeError:
module 'm' has no attribute 'f'.

How can I get it to print

function Bark at 0x000000?

Comment: Do you mean: `print(f)` to print all stuff in `__all__`?

Comment: Cause from what you type, it could be `print(m.'bark')` which mostly trigger error.

Comment: `__all__` is a list of function names. Do `getattr(m, f)` to get the function objects associated with the names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where you have a string containing the attribute name, use [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) to get the attribute:

```
print(getattr(m, f))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import m
for name in dir(m):
    item = getattr(m, name)
    print(f"{name} is {type(item)}")
    if isinstance(item, types.FunctionType):
        print(f"{name} is a function!")
        # can call function thusly:
        # item(args...)
```

Now, do you really want to know if the item is a function, or do you want to know if it's callable?  Those are two different things.  You can use `isinstance(item, types.FunctionType)` as shown above, but see [How do I detect whether a Python variable is a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624926/how-do-i-detect-whether-a-python-variable-is-a-function) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, function_list return all name and function of an object as a dictionary.

```
from types import FunctionType

def function_list(module):
    return {key:value for key, value in module.__dict__.items()
                if type(value) == FunctionType}
```