# Why does a built-in function class throw NameError when trying to reference it?

Tags: python

I don't understand why when executing

```
def foo():
    pass

print(type(foo))
print(isinstance(foo, function))
```

The output is

```
<class 'function'>
NameError: name 'function' is not defined
```

But when executing

```
foo = list()

print(type(foo))
print(isinstance(foo, list))
```

The output is

```
<class 'list'>
True
```

Why does the first execution result in a `NameError` when `function` is clearly a valid class? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check out this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/624926/how-do-i-detect-whether-a-python-variable-is-a-function

Comment: What do you not understand? There is no name `function` in the built-in namespace, and you haven't defined that variable anywhere. There is a type, though, which is the type of function objects. That exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`function` is the name of the implementing class for user-defined functions, but it's not an *exposed* name (not part of the built-ins you can see anywhere).

For a similar example, imagine a module named `foomodule.py` with these contents:

```
class Foo:
    pass

def make_foo():
    return Foo()
```

If you do this in another module:

```
from foomodule import make_foo

x = make_foo()
print(type(x))
```

it will tell you that it's a `foomodule.Foo`. But if you do:

```
print(isinstance(x, foomodule.Foo))
```

you'll get a `NameError`, because you can't actually see that qualified name in your current scope; it exists, but it's not "published" where you're looking for it (the current module's global scope).

In a similar way, the `function` class the implements user-defined functions *exists*, but it's not directly published.

As it happens, you can find it published on the `types` module as `types.FunctionType`, but they get a reference to it the same way you did; by defining a user-defined function and calling `type` on it. The type just isn't *directly* exposed at the Python level in any way shy of pulling it from an existing function with `type`.

There are other examples of this in the built-ins, e.g. `type(None)` is a class named `NoneType`, but the only way to access it is via `type(None)`; there's no reason to publish it directly. You can't manually make your own instances of `NoneType` in a useful way; similarly, user-defined functions are made with `def`, not the `function` constructor.

Comment: It is *exposed*, it's just not in the built-in namespace.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: This one is *barely* exposed, and only insofar as *all* classes are exposed if you have access to their instances. I feel I made that fairly clear (in that I described what I meant by "not exposed" and showed you how you gain access to it).